# Use awk to delete everything after the ","

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, regular-expression

I have a variable, `var`, that contains:

```
XXXX YY ZZZZZ\n
aaa,bbb,ccc
```

All I want is `aaa` in the second line.
I tried:

```
out=$(echo "$var" | awk 'NR==2{sub(",.*","")}' )
```

but I get no output. I tried using `,` as the FS but I can't get the syntax right. I really want to learn awk/regex syntax.

I want to use out as a variable "$out" somewhere else -- not to print.

Comment: re. "I want to use out as a variable "$out" somewhere else not to print.", the command to extract a particular part of the input is the same regardless of if you capture the output with a command substitution or not. (well, as long as you use an external command to do it anyway.) Just wrap the `out=$(...)` around it.

Comment: It is impossible for the script you posted to produce the error message you say it does. We can't help you if you don't show us the problem you need help with. By the way, having a variable that contains a multi-line string is usually a sign that you have the wrong approach earlier in your script.

Comment: Please try harder to explain what you want.  For starters, ***EXACTLY*** what output do you want for the sample input you show: ```aaa```, `XXXX YY ZZZZZ` *`<newline>`* `aaa`, `XXXX YY ZZZZZ\naaa` or `XXXX YY ZZZZZ\n` *`<newline>`* `aaa`?  Then, show more examples (of input ***and corresponding desired output***).  For example, (1) only one line, (2) more than two lines, (3) first line contains comma(s), (4) second line doesn’t contain commas, etc.  Try to cover all the functionality that you want as thoroughly as you can.  … (Cont’d)

Answer (score 17):

You don't want regexes there. The entire point of `awk` is to automatically split a line into fields, so just set the field separator to `,` and print the first field of the second line:

```
$ printf '%s' "$var" | awk -F, 'NR==2{print $1}'
aaa
```

Or, if your shell supports `<<<`:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==2{print $1}' <<<"$var"
aaa
```

If you really want to do it manually and not use `awk` as intended, you can do:

```
$ awk 'NR==2{sub(/,.*/,""); print}' <<<"$var"
aaa
```

You were getting no output because you didn't tell `awk` to print anything.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you could also use the `${param#pattern}` and `${param%%pattern}` standard parameter expansion operators here:

```
NL='
'
out=${var#*"$NL"} # removes first line. Assumes there are at least 2
out=${out%%"$NL"*} # removes all but the first line
out=${out%%,*} # removes everything after the first ,
```

Or with `bash` specifically, you could use:

```
LC_ALL=C # needed to accept non-text
[[ $var =~ ^[^$'\n']*$'\n'([^,$'\n']*) ]]
out=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Standardly, there's also `expr`:

```
NL='
'
out=$(LC_ALL=C expr "x$var" : "[^$NL]*$NL\([^,$NL]*\)")
```

The problem in your approach is that you don't tell `awk` to print anything. If `awk` doesn't print anything, then nothing will be stored in the variable as `$(...)` expands to the output of the command inside¹. Also, remember `echo` can't be used to print arbitrary data.

```
out=$(printf '%s\n' "$var" | awk 'NR == 2 {sub(",.*", ""); print}')
```

Or:

```
out=$(printf '%s\n' "$var" | awk -F, 'NR == 2 {print $1}')
```

---

<sup>¹ minus the trailing newline characters, and with behaviour varying between shell implementations if the output contains NUL bytes</sup>

Comment: I don't want to print the results. I want to use the output as a variable.

Comment: @Dark_Stoner, see edit. You do want awk to print something so that output can be stored in the variable.

Comment: I got you. Thanks so much. Starting to get a handle on what aw requires.

Comment: I;m going to use your solutions  because they register with my thought process

Answer (score 7):

Another option using `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/,.*$//p' <<< "$var"
```

- This will substitute (`s/../../`) everything starting from the first `,` on each line to the end of the line (`,.*$`) with "nothing", thereby leaving only the part *before* the first `,`.
- By using the `-n` option, output is suppressed by default. The `p` at the end of the program instructs `sed` to still print lines where the "search" pattern was found. That way, we ignore the first line (without `,`) and only process the second line, where a `,` was actually found.

As usual, you can import the result into a shell variable via command substitution:

```bash
out=$(sed -n 's/,.*$//p' <<< "$var")
```

or, in shells that don't understand here-strings,

```bash
out=$(printf '%s' "$var" | sed -n 's/,.*$//p')
```

---

Notice that since you didn't include examples of fringe cases, it is difficult to taylor the solution to accomodate all possible content of `$var`. The current solution assumes that there is only one line with a `,`, from which you want to extract the first field.

Comment: I can't tell you how much that helped me out. Thanks so much.

Comment: While this will *probably* work for the OP, if the first line contains a comma, it will produce extra stuff. This should be trivially fixable by adding a `2` to the beginning of the sed expressions.

Comment: @Matthew The problem is that the OP's description doesn't include fringe cases, so it is impossible to tell if the first line could also include a `,`, or whether it is actually the _last_ line the OP wants to parse and this only happens to coincide with the second line in the given example. You are right that your modification would accomodate the former case, but then the answer would be a replication of the [other answer by Praveen Kumar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/669182/377345) so I will just mention the limitations in a caveat.

Answer (score 6):

```
awk -F, '/,/ {print $1}' <<< "$var"
```

This tells `awk` to use a comma character as the field delimiter,
and to search for any line which contains a comma.  Once a line containing
a comma is found, awk is told to print the first field from that line, i.e.
everything up to but not including the first comma.

Comment: Thanks sooo much.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '2s/,.*//p' <<<"$var"
aaa
```

---

specifically if you are reading from a large file it's good to set a break point after your command proceed the second line.

```
$ sed -n '2{s/,.*//p;q;}' infile
```

this will `q`uit the later processing on the input file.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `awk`  could be:

```
awk -F, '{ getline; print $1 }' <<<"$var"
```

The field delimiter is `,` then `getline` will jump to the next line and print the first record

Edge case:

If `var` contains the following:

```
var="foo bar baz\n
aaa,bbb,ccc\n
qux foo\n
ddd,eee,fff"
```

then

```
aaa
ddd
```

would be printed.

Comment: If the input contains only one line, that will print the first field of the first line though.

Comment: in general, it'll print _all_ even-numbered lines, and if the input has an odd number of lines, also the last odd line. Which is not the same as just printing the second line, like the code in the question does.

Comment: I agree. I might have taken the question too verbatim. For the above usecase it works but I can imagine that if the var contains `foo\nbar\nbaz\nqux` it would print `bar` and `qux`. For this very specific case imho it does just that.

Comment: @ValentinBajrami I suggest to add notes **to your answer** that this code will produce the expected result with the input shown in the question and what would happen for other possible input.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Bodo. Added some explanation there!

Comment: I would cite the explanation from ilkkachu's comment because it is more general compared to your single example. Comments can get deleted later, and all important information should be in the answer itself.

Comment: I think I made my point clear. There are already good answers. If I'd have to change the answer what's the point of it?   It then would look all the same :).  Also maybe if only this is to intoduce the `getline` in awk. Cheers

Comment: Don't do this. This is not an appropriate (or even useful) use of `getline` and it's not being used safely. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: I can't tell you how much that helped me out. Thanks so much. Hmm, I guess II just did tell you.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
echo "XXXX YY ZZZZZZZ
aaa,bbb,ccc" | awk -F,  '{print $1}'
XXXX YY ZZZZZZZ
aaa
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f1
```

will give you the first field (`-f1`) until the delimiter `-d`

If you want the last line only, you can pipe from `tail`. Or pipe from `sed` to get a specific line.

```
tail -n1 <<< "$var" | cut -d, -f1
sed -n 2p <<< "$var" | cut -d, -f1
```

Comment: Thanx for your input. haven't used cut yet yet.